# UI Bug After UI has interaction

Tags: unity, c#

I am making a 3rd person game for pc. Space, of course, makes the player jump in game. For some reason if I interact with my menu at all and then press space it will open my menu back up. This doesn't happen if I don't interact with the UI first though. I don't know if this is a bug or what but my code does not contain anything that would take input from the keyboard in general so the space bar interacting with it doesn't make sense. Has anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: This sounds similar to [this recent question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/130238/39518) — have you tried remapping the UI "Submit" action so it doesn't use the Space key? (It's the alt positive button for this action in the default mapping)

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks for that. It solved my problem. If you submit an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I went into the Input Manager and deleted the alt positive button action for "Submit" as this was set to space by default. By just removing space from that the issue no longer exists.